# Negative exponent in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am new to bash script and stuck with a problem. I am trying to run some quantity that starts from say 10^-5 and goes to 10^-3 in steps of 10^{-3.5}. How do I write this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is that an arithmetic series or a geometric series?